# Adding a button inside an ngbNavLink

Tags: angular, tabs, ng-bootstrap

Hi I'm really new to angular and I have this request adding a button inside a ngbNavLink just next to the tab title.
There will be 2 actions so it doesn't work for me.

```
              <ng-container ngbNavItem>
                    <div class="d-flex">
                      <div ngbNavLink>
                          <a (click)="loadData(); ">Informations</a> 
                        
                          <div class="d-flex p-2">
                              <button
                              type="button"
                              id="editDataButton"
                              placement="bottom">
                              <fa-icon [icon]="fasPencil" size="lg"></fa-icon>
                            </button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
            </ng-container>
```

This solution gives me the following :
[image]

The tab action and the button work, but I loose the tab border.

Any help will be appreciated